# Visual Studio 2019. In my Project Configuration settings I cannot change from Debug to Release

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

In my Project Configuration settings (where you change your configuration and platform settings) I cannot change one of my settings to release, the only option is Debug.

As seen here:

[image]

What can I do? I am sorry if this is an easy question, I just can't fix it.

Comment: This could happen if you accidentally removed the Release config for that particular project.Right-click that project (not the solution) in Solution Explorer, open Properties and check what's listed under Configurations.

Comment: Hi, I fixed my issue. Luckily I have only accidently deleted the Release config for the first project. So I made another config from the pre-existing release config and applied that to the all existing projects. Thank you for your help!